# Apache discards ETag header when using Nginx in ProxyPass

Tags: apache, nginx, proxypass, etag

Good day everyone. I just noticed rather weird behavior when using ProxyPass from Apache to Nginx, let me demonstrate and ask if anyone encountered something similar..

Minimal set-up is like this:

Apache:

```
LogLevel trace6

SSLProxyEngine On
SSLProxyCheckPeerName Off
SSLProxyCheckPeerCN Off

<LocationMatch "\.js$">
    ProxyPassMatch https://static-assets.dev.com:4430
    ProxyPassReverse https://static-assets.dev.com:4430
</LocationMatch>
```

Nginx:

```
server {
    listen *:4430 default_server ssl;

    ssl_certificate     /etc/nginx/ssl/ssl.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/ssl.key;

    server_name static-assets.dev.com;

    root /assets;

    etag on;
    gzip off;

    server_tokens off;

    add_header X-Hi-From-Nginx $sent_http_etag;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
}
```

Then in Apache log I see this:

```
[Thu Feb 21 14:49:18.762737 2019] [proxy_http:trace3] [pid 895:tid 139989845219072] mod_proxy_http.c(1424): [client 172.17.0.1:40486] Status from backend: 200
[Thu Feb 21 14:49:18.762744 2019] [proxy_http:trace4] [pid 895:tid 139989845219072] mod_proxy_http.c(1099): [client 172.17.0.1:40486] Headers received from backend:
[Thu Feb 21 14:49:18.762749 2019] [proxy_http:trace4] [pid 895:tid 139989845219072] mod_proxy_http.c(1101): [client 172.17.0.1:40486] Server: nginx
[Thu Feb 21 14:49:18.762752 2019] [proxy_http:trace4] [pid 895:tid 139989845219072] mod_proxy_http.c(1101): [client 172.17.0.1:40486] Date: Thu, 21 Feb 2019 06:49:18 GMT
[Thu Feb 21 14:49:18.762759 2019] [proxy_http:trace4] [pid 895:tid 139989845219072] mod_proxy_http.c(1101): [client 172.17.0.1:40486] Content-Type: application/javascript
[Thu Feb 21 14:49:18.762762 2019] [proxy_http:trace4] [pid 895:tid 139989845219072] mod_proxy_http.c(1101): [client 172.17.0.1:40486] Content-Length: 1130146
[Thu Feb 21 14:49:18.762765 2019] [proxy_http:trace4] [pid 895:tid 139989845219072] mod_proxy_http.c(1101): [client 172.17.0.1:40486] Last-Modified: Mon, 18 Feb 2019 05:11:04 GMT
[Thu Feb 21 14:49:18.762768 2019] [proxy_http:trace4] [pid 895:tid 139989845219072] mod_proxy_http.c(1101): [client 172.17.0.1:40486] Connection: keep-alive
[Thu Feb 21 14:49:18.762771 2019] [proxy_http:trace4] [pid 895:tid 139989845219072] mod_proxy_http.c(1101): [client 172.17.0.1:40486] ETag: "5c6a3e68-113ea2"
[Thu Feb 21 14:49:18.762773 2019] [proxy_http:trace4] [pid 895:tid 139989845219072] mod_proxy_http.c(1101): [client 172.17.0.1:40486] X-Hi-From-Nginx: "5c6a3e68-113ea2"
[Thu Feb 21 14:49:18.762776 2019] [proxy_http:trace4] [pid 895:tid 139989845219072] mod_proxy_http.c(1101): [client 172.17.0.1:40486] Accept-Ranges: bytes
[Thu Feb 21 14:49:18.762783 2019] [proxy_http:trace3] [pid 895:tid 139989845219072] mod_proxy_http.c(1695): [client 172.17.0.1:40486] start body send

[Thu Feb 21 14:49:18.762837 2019] [http:trace3] [pid 895:tid 139989845219072] http_filters.c(1129): [client 172.17.0.1:40486] Response sent with status 200, headers:
[Thu Feb 21 14:49:18.762841 2019] [http:trace5] [pid 895:tid 139989845219072] http_filters.c(1136): [client 172.17.0.1:40486]   Date: Thu, 21 Feb 2019 06:49:18 GMT
[Thu Feb 21 14:49:18.762844 2019] [http:trace5] [pid 895:tid 139989845219072] http_filters.c(1139): [client 172.17.0.1:40486]   Server: nginx
[Thu Feb 21 14:49:18.762847 2019] [http:trace4] [pid 895:tid 139989845219072] http_filters.c(958): [client 172.17.0.1:40486]   Content-Type: application/javascript
[Thu Feb 21 14:49:18.762849 2019] [http:trace4] [pid 895:tid 139989845219072] http_filters.c(958): [client 172.17.0.1:40486]   Content-Length: 1130146
[Thu Feb 21 14:49:18.762852 2019] [http:trace4] [pid 895:tid 139989845219072] http_filters.c(958): [client 172.17.0.1:40486]   Last-Modified: Mon, 18 Feb 2019 05:11:04 GMT
[Thu Feb 21 14:49:18.762854 2019] [http:trace4] [pid 895:tid 139989845219072] http_filters.c(958): [client 172.17.0.1:40486]   X-Hi-From-Nginx: \\"5c6a3e68-113ea2\\"
[Thu Feb 21 14:49:18.762857 2019] [http:trace4] [pid 895:tid 139989845219072] http_filters.c(958): [client 172.17.0.1:40486]   Accept-Ranges: bytes
[Thu Feb 21 14:49:18.762859 2019] [http:trace4] [pid 895:tid 139989845219072] http_filters.c(958): [client 172.17.0.1:40486]   Vary: Accept-Encoding
```

So basically it discards ETag header, however my custom X-Hi-From-Nginx header with same value is passed without any issue. I read Nginx can have some troubles with ETag when gzip is enabled, however disabling it doesn't improves anything. And actually it's clear that problem is on Apache side as Nginx sends all the headers as expected.

Here's software I'm using (via Docker):

```
root@7ac07b106612:/bootstrap# nginx -v
nginx version: nginx/1.10.3 (Ubuntu)
root@7ac07b106612:/bootstrap# apache2ctl -v
Server version: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
Server built:   2018-06-07T19:43:03
```

Next day update..

I actually managed to set one more custom header using expr like this:

```
Header always set X-Apache-ETag "expr=%{resp:x-nginx-etag}"
Header always set ETag "expr=%{resp:x-nginx-etag}"
```

However it only sets "X-Apache-ETag" header, while ETag is still discarded. It starts to look as some bug already..

```
> GET /dist/js/vendor.js HTTP/1.1
> Host: dev.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.53.0
> Accept: */*
> Accept-encoding: br
>
{ [5 bytes data]
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Fri, 22 Feb 2019 04:55:10 GMT
< Server: nginx
< X-Apache-ETag: "5c6f3469-4ad21"
< Content-Type: application/javascript
< Content-Length: 306465
< Last-Modified: Thu, 21 Feb 2019 23:29:45 GMT
< X-Nginx-Etag: "5c6f3469-4ad21"
< Accept-Ranges: bytes
< Vary: Accept-Encoding
```

Update #2. Few more details.. I saw it says "http_filters.c" near "Response sent with status 200, headers:", so I started to google for the source of that file. And [here](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/httpd/httpd/branches/2.4.x/modules/http/http_filters.c?annotate=1840572#l1414) is what I found:

```
/*
 * Now remove any ETag response header field if earlier processing
 * says so (such as a 'FileETag None' directive).
 */
if (apr_table_get(r->notes, "no-etag") != NULL) {
    apr_table_unset(r->headers_out, "ETag");
}
```

Not sure why this condition triggers as I don't have "FileETag None" nowhere in my configs. And even if I add "FileETag MTime Size" it doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Update #3 ..

I figured this was caused by the loaded "include" module. It has this certain [SSIETag](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_include.html#ssietag) directive which is set to "Off" by default - based on the description that leads to "no-etag" notes and to the header disappearing eventually.

Setting it to "On" in  context doesn't help much, however disabling "include" module completely does help, so this is the culprit.